# A good front-end web file manager that can be integrated with a linux server

Tags: linux, file-management

Hi I'm helping develop a intranet site. And I'm looking for a front-end file manager with this characteristics:

- Can connect by SFTP or FTP to a Linux server;
- Permit multiple file uploads, if possible with technology drop file;
- With multipel languages (English, Portuguese, Spanish, German, French);
- Permit workflow;
- With content search capacity;
- Permit folder and File sharing;
- Editing doc files in the server, if possible by two or more users at the same time;
- With permissions of (Read, write, execute).

I've been looking for two days and just found solutions for Windows servers, but the specifications for the site is for a linux server.

The solutions I found to my specifications are vulnerable to attacks or do not have all the specifications and some are instabel. Examples:

. net2ftp;

. Marlin.

I'm open for paid solutions, but the price can not be more than 1000€.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: So you are trying to connect to a Linux server, am I correct? What's the operating system you are using?

Comment: @Sahan Serasinghe I can connect to the server and I have a simple download that works. What I want is a file manager that has the characteristics I've specified. This to save some development time.

Comment: Did you try Filezilla?

Comment: @Sahan Serasinghe I didn't try, because the server side it's for windows only, and I need to run in a Linux server. But I'm going to investigate a little better, maybe something has escaped me.